# DNS not resolving even though nameserver has propagated?

Tags: domains, dns, resolution

I have a custom name server. ns1.buildingautomationmonthly.com. It has propagated according to DNS checker. I can go to philzito.com and buildingautomationbook.com which are both using the name server (they both also show propagation in the DNS checker site).

However, buildingautomationmonthly.com which has the same name server is not propagating after 12 hours. My only thought is that since I am using a private registration for the buildingautomationmonthly.com that is causing the delay? But why would that be the case as that should have nothing to do with DNS to IP resolution.

All of my domains come from GoDaddy and I've triple checked that they have the same settings.

Comment: You shouldn't use a custom DNS name for your nameservers.  DNS hosting is cheap and reliable.  Don't try to build your own.  Building your own is more complicated, you'll need glue records.  You won't have enough redundancy.  You need at least two servers in different parts of the globe, but ideally you should have four.   See my answer here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/48993/using-one-ip-for-nameserver-like-ns1-and-ns2/48999#48999

Comment: I was told by hostgator that since I am using their VPS that I have to use a custom name server.

Here is what their email said.

If everything is working properly, then each of your domains will need to be updated at your domain registrar(s) with these nameservers:
ns1.buildingautomationmonthly.com with IP address 198.57.235.163
ns2.buildingautomationmonthly.com with IP address 198.57.235.162

Comment: The only time that you want custom nameservers is when you are running your own web host and you want your name in the name servers for your customers.   With a VPS can use somebody else's nameservers and create an A record in your DNS zone that points to the IP address of your VPS.  Super simple.

Comment: Hostgator has DNS servers that you can use.  They say that using their DNS servers is the preferred solution: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/dns-name-servers/how-do-i-change-my-dns-or-name-servers

Comment: Here is Hostgators article about private DNS servers: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/private-name-servers   They recommend that if you are a reseller.  If you are selling hosting on your VPS.

Comment: Man gotta love hostgator, they mentioned absolutely none of this when I switched to a VPS. They simply said, add the private name servers to your domain registrar.

Comment: Steve YOU ARE A LIVESAVER. It was that one piece in the article you linked to. I added the ns1 and ns2 to the A name and everything works now! If only hostgator had included that step in their email to me :-D

Answer (score 1):

Domain name being private has no impact on propagation.

When I go to your site, it shows this error message from cPanel:

"There has been a server misconfiguration.
You must verify that your hosting provider has the correct IP address configured for your Apache settings and DNS records. A restart of Apache may be required for new settings to take affect."

It indicates there's some misconfig. Do you not see the error?

Comment: You are talking about the default result when you hit the IP address correct? http://198.57.235.163/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Comment: See the issue is Philzito.com and buildingautomationbook.com which are subdomains on the server work perfectly fine. Its the buildingautomationmonthly.com domain which is on the server that is not resolving.

Comment: No, I saw that error on ns1.buildingautomationmonthly.com, not on the IP address. Both buildingautomationmonthly.com and philzito.com ping to the same IP and seems both sites are working for me. At least it seems to have propagated to my ISP in New York

Comment: Please keep in mind that some telecoms cache DNS records for a period. At one point AT&T cached DNS records for as much as a year. Not anymore but still likely cached. Most cache for a week. If you are trying to access your site from your cell phone, you may be hitting a DNS cache. It is fairly likely the case. This can also be true for subscriber access at home too, though less likely. For example, non-telecoms such as cable or satellite may cache whereas telecoms such as your land line DSL may not except for a few hours or a day.